# vimgrep wildcard as file extension

Tags: vim, vimgrep

How can I search using the `vimgrep` command for a pattern in current dir recursively in all the files no mater what extension they have.

In console I can do: `grep -r <pattern> *.*`

After doing some search on google I found out that in vim I can search for a pattern recursively in files with certain extension like so:

`:vimgrep /<pattern>/g **/*.extension`

After reading the help from vim for `:help starstar-wildcard` which I found in `help vimgrep` I didn't find any explanation how can i match any file extension except the `**/*` from the starstar-wildcard help.

Tried:
`:vimgrep /<pattern>/g **/*` and I get this error: `Cannot open file "**/*"`

even tried to escape the wildcard character like so:
`:vimgrep /<pattern>/g **/\*` same result `Cannot open file "**/*"`

My vim version is: `VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Jan 10 2014 09:33:13)` and I have tried with a new user without any .vimrc config file and the result is the same.

Is there a way to search like grep does but using :vimgrep inside vim?

Comment: I use `:vimgrep /<pattern>/ **` all the time.  I just tried `:vimgrep /<pattern>/g **/*` and did not get an error message.  I even tried `:set cp`, with no difference.  What OS are you using?

Comment: @benjifisher - This is my OS: `Linux arch 3.12.9-2-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Fri Jan 31 10:22:54 CET 2014 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: If the answer had been "Windows" then the problem might have been that `/` is not the path separator.  What happens if you just try `**` instead of `**/*`?  Can you show me exactly the command you are using?  (I am guessing that it does not literally include "<pattern>".)

Comment: @benjifisher `:vimgrep /a/g **/*` this is the command that I'm trying. Same result with `**` - `Cannot open file "**"`. I will try to wipe all files related to vim and uninstall & reinstall vim. Hope this will work.

Comment: I am getting desperate here, trying to think of an explanation.  "When all else has been ruled out as impossible, ..."  The error message suggests that `**` is not recognized as a special sequence.  Reading `:help starstar` and then scrolling up to the start of the section, I see `{not available when compiled without the |+path_extra| feature}`.  You only gave the first line of `:version`:  perhaps you are using a tiny, system-installed vim?  More to the point, what does `:echo has('path_extra')` tell you?

Comment: @benjifisher I have cleaned all my files reinstalled and It is working OK. What should I do with the question? Should I delete it? Thank you for your help.

Comment: When I do `:echo has('path_extra')`, the output is "1".  But I have the same problem as the OP.  @benjifisher